# Using Rx to join a throttled TextBox.TextChanged with TextBox.GotFocus/(delayed)LostFocus throws a System.OperationCanceledException

Tags: c#, wpf, system.reactive

I am using Rx to create som kind of "ProbablyDoneTyping" for TextBoxes in WPF.

I got everyting to work by joining an Observable from GotFocus with an Observable from TextChanged like this

```
var gotFocus = Observable.FromEventPattern<RoutedEventArgs>(textBox, "GotFocus");
var delayedLostFocus = Observable.FromEventPattern<RoutedEventArgs>(textBox, "LostFocus")
    .Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(850));

var throttledTextChanged = Observable.FromEventPattern<TextChangedEventArgs>(textBox, "TextChanged")
    .Select(pattern => textBox.Text).Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(750)).DistinctUntilChanged();
var immediately = Observable.Empty<Unit>();

var probablyDoneTyping = gotFocus.Join(throttledTextChanged, _ => delayedLostFocus, _ => immediately, (_, text) => text);
probablyDoneTyping.ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current).Subscribe(text => Title = text);
```

I intruduced the delay on LostFocus so that I am able to leave the TextBox and the probablyDoneTyping still fires.

But this gives me a System.OperationCanceledException that originates in the Delay every time i leave the textBox.

The stack trace for the exception is

```
System.Reactive.Linq.dll!System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Delay<System.Reactive.EventPattern<System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs>>.LongRunningImpl.DrainQueue Normal
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.Wait(int millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)  
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.SemaphoreSlim.Wait(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)   
System.Reactive.Linq.dll!System.Reactive.Linq.ObservableImpl.Delay<System.Reactive.EventPattern<System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs>>.LongRunningImpl.DrainQueue(System.Reactive.Disposables.ICancelable cancel)  
System.Reactive.Core.dll!System.Reactive.Concurrency.Scheduler.ScheduleLongRunning.AnonymousMethod__72(System.Action<System.Reactive.Disposables.ICancelable> a, System.Reactive.Disposables.ICancelable c)  
System.Reactive.Core.dll!System.Reactive.Concurrency.DefaultScheduler.LongRunning.ScheduleLongRunning<System.Action<System.Reactive.Disposables.ICancelable>>.AnonymousMethod__b(object arg)     
System.Reactive.PlatformServices.dll!System.Reactive.Concurrency.ConcurrencyAbstractionLayerImpl.StartThread.AnonymousMethod__4()    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state)     
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)  
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

The exception does not affect my application but it is thrown and if I breake for Common Language Runtime Exceptions the application will stop every time I leave a TextBox. I do not want this.

Why is the exception thrown and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: From the source code below, the Delay method should catch the Exception. What version of Rx are you using ?  https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/System.Reactive.Linq/Reactive/Linq/Observable/Delay.cs

Comment: I am using version 2.2.5

Comment: Ok, I can see from the SourceCode that the exception is caught. And what i can gather from this, is that this is the expected behavior and will have to love with it.

Answer (score 0):

Enable [Just My Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85yzd16c.aspx) or disable [breaking on first-chance exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx) (though I don't recommend the latter).